# Component doesn't return the new elements after updating state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I have 3 elements and I want to add a new element by clicking on any div, but the problem is after adding new elements to the array they don't get rendered out of the component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let elements = [
    { id: 0, text: "first" },
    { id: 1, text: "second" },
    { id: 2, text: "third" }
  ];
  const [state, setstate] = useState(elements);
  function handleClick() {
    elements.push({ id: 3, text: "xxx", checkBox: null });
    setstate(elements);
    console.log(state); //state shows 4 elememnt but they don't render in 
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map((e) => (
        // why this don't render the new elements?
        <div onClick={handleClick}>{e.text}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`in codesandbox` https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-silence-c1t1k?file=/src/App.js:0-641

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not mutate the state directly**, it's not a good practice. Instead try as:

```
function handleClick() {
    setstate(prevState => [
       ...prevState,
       { id: 3, text: "xxx", checkBox: null }
    ])
}
```

By doing this you are cloning the previous state of the array and adding that new element into the copy of the array what you can pass to `setState` function.

See the working CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-framework-7ymyw?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: aha thank you....also, do you know  how to update { id: 0, text: "first" } to  { id: 0, text: "update." }?

Answer (score 1):

You should **not mutate the state directly**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const defaultElements = [
  { id: 0, text: "first" },
  { id: 1, text: "second" },
  { id: 2, text: "third" }
];

const newElement = {
  id: 3,
  text: "xxx",
  checkBox: null
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(defaultElements);

  function handleClick() {
    setState((item) => [...item, newElement]);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.map(({ text }, index) => (
        <div key={index} onClick={handleClick}>
          {text}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```